# Most efficient way to str.replace regex=True or similar in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

Dozens of strings need to be replaced across multiple columns of thousands of dfs:

```py
for df in dfs:
    for col in columns:
        for key, value in replacement_strs.items():
            df[col] = df[col].str.replace(key, value, regex=True)
```

Iterations of above take milliseconds but added up this takes hours, so we need something more efficient.

Could we apply `re_sub` or similar in a more efficient way? [Use CstringIO like this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661091/4107349) somehow? [Some kind of vectorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4107349)?

Applying `str.replace` might be more efficient after combining dfs but [`pd.concat()` blows out of available memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55740613/pandas-concat-is-running-into-memory-error).

Edit: Crude reproducible example below. Note how elapsed time increases linearly with number of dfs when total number of cells is held constant by reducing rows per df (play with `shape[0]` and `range(0,1000)`):

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, string, random
from timeit import default_timer as timer
np.random.seed(123)

dfs = []
shape = [500, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(shape[0] * shape[1]).reshape(shape[0],shape[1])).applymap(lambda x: np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters.upper())))

for n in range(0,1000):
    dfs.append(df)

start = timer()

for df in dfs:
    for col in [col for col in range(0,shape[1])]:
        for key, value in {'A$': 'W','B': 'X','C[a-z]': 'Y','D': 'Z',}.items():
            df[col] = df[col].str.replace(key, value, regex=True)

end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: A reproducible example of two/three small dfs, the dictionary, and the expected output would be useful/helpful

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you could use pandas [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), along with your dictionary, and a comprehension to get your output, with improved speed:

```
mapping = {'A$': 'W','B': 'X','C[a-z]': 'Y','D': 'Z',}
[entry.replace(mapping, regex = False) for entry in dfs]
```

On my PC, your function runs in 17s, while the list comprehension above runs in 1.2s. There may be improvements (generators, multiprocessing). Using [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) is a good start, before further optimisation (if really needed).

Comment: Looks great but some cols shouldn't have `replace` applied, which I didn't think to include in example. Can we do this on only some columns?

Comment: sure, you can select the columns you are interested in. Are the selected columns same for all the dataframes?

Comment: Yup, although I have since found the vast majority of processing time to be caused by applying replace before concatenating. After moving `replace` to groups of `pd.concat()` the issue was largely resolved.